# Custom view FloatingActionButton has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am very confused by the warning I get because I am not using a custom class, I am simply using a Floating Action Button. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this issue?

" Custom view `FloatingActionButton` has `setOnTouchListener` called on it but does not override `performClick` "

```
FloatingActionButton touchFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        touchFab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        round.setRound();
                        round.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        return false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        round.setEndTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
//                      setRecordedTime(round.getTimeDiff());
                        round.afterRound();
                        createFragment();
                        return false;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

relevant XML for the FAB.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="#FFF"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

After some testing, it appears the problem is just with Android Studio 3.0 Canary, I just went back to the stable version of Studio and no error. If someone could understand why the warning was popping up for the new version that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. 
My result override method performClick():

```
class FAButton(context: Context?) : FloatingActionButton(context){
    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        return super.performClick()
    }
}
```